# Xamarin forms WebView losing Session/Cookie

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview

I'm using a `Webview` in a Xamarin Forms application. I'm setting a specific cookie as we can see in the code below.

**Problem:** `Webview` is opening correctly and the page is loaded, but the web site contain a Next button which will lead us to another web page. Whenever I'm pressing Next, I'm getting a **Session Timeout** directly. It's like the Webview won't save the cookie when I navigate inside of it.

**WebScreen.xaml:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="EPayment.Views.DetailViews.WebScreen">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="paymentWebView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Navigated="paymentWebView_Navigated" Navigating="paymentWebView_Navigating"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**WebScreen.xaml.cs:**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class WebScreen : ContentPage
{
    public WebScreen(HtmlWebViewSource webSource)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        paymentWebView.Source = webSource;
    }

    private void paymentWebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e) { }

    private void paymentWebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e) { }
}
```

Here's how I'm initiating the `WebScreen` class:

```
var httpDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("r");
var cookieValue = httpDate;
var encodedCookie = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cookieValue);
cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("cookie", encodedCookie));
var result = await client.PostAsync("/pay", content);
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var resp = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var html = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
        Html = resp,
        BaseUrl = "https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com"
    };
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new WebScreen(html));
}
```

Anyone know what's the solution for this kind of problem? Is there a way to save cookies or an option or something like that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the Session TimeOut exception. Have you try to set the cookies for the webview? Check the link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#cookies

Comment: Yes I've tried and the same thing happened

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. The website seems created by yourself. Could you provide a demo code which coud reproduce?